# Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, production, angular-aot

Using `[(ngModel)]`, I managed to set an inputs value based on a selected dropdown but I'm getting an **error** when compiling using `ng build --configuration=prod`, **error** shown is

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'any[]'
>
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'any[]'

when I compiled using `ng serve`, there was no **error**, Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsuxey) I created and what I have tried so far,

**Typescript file:**

```
  savedCards = [];
  selectedCard = '';

      selectDropdownCard(card) {
        this.savedCards.find((item) => item.id === card.id) ?
          this.savedCards = this.savedCards.filter((item) => item.id === card.id) :
          this.savedCards = [card];
        this.show = false;
        this.hasSelected = true;
        this.selectedCard = card;
      }
```

**HTML file**

```
<div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard" ngDefaultControl>
  <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
    <div>
      <p>dropdown</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngFor="let card of savedCards">
    <div>
      <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="div2" *ngIf="show">
  <div *ngFor="let card of savedCreditCards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
    <div>
      <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<input placeholder="id" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.id" type="text">
<input placeholder="viewValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.viewValue" type="text">
<input placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.name" type="text">
<input placeholder="value" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.value" type="text">
```

if I try added interface and use it as type, on `ng build --configuration=prod` I got no **error**, but on `ng serve` **error** shown are:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

I could use some guidance and suggestions since I could not figure out how to solve this.

Comment: You should always create a class and its object for a better coding practice. Since object of type `any` means anything, just anything.

Comment: I don't see cardHolder in the code shown. Where is it?

Comment: @ShravilPotdar even I had create class I still got error on ng serve

Comment: @PankajShukla got it, my fault, supposed to be 'value'

Comment: Is your problem solved now?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing selectedCard as an empty String, Initialize it as an empty Object, that should solve your problem, I hope this helps.

```
  selectedCard = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an interface and use it as a type ?

```
interface Card {
    id: string;
    viewValue: string;
    name: string;
    value: string;
}
...
selectedCard: Card = { id = '', viewValue = '', name = '', value = '' };
```

Or have you tried something like that :

```
selectedCard = { id = '', viewValue = '', name = '', value = '' };
```

Comment: In your stackblitz, your are not using a property 'cardHolder'. Did you copy/paste all your code ?

Comment: I tried localy, i create an interface and put that : `selectedCard: Card = { id = '', viewValue = '', name = '', value = '' };`. (p.s: I forgot one `;` in the interface at `value: string`) and I have no **error**.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `selectedCard` is set to undefined or ''. So if you can assign the default value to `selectedCard` which could be first element of savedCreditCards then you should not get this error. I am not sure if that is possible for you to do but if it is then do:

```
savedCards = [];
  show = false;
  hasSelected: boolean;
  savedCreditCards: Card[] = [
    { id: '001', viewValue: 'Dropdown1', name: 'A' , value:'1' },
    { id: '002', viewValue: 'Dropdown2', name: 'B' , value:'2' },
    { id: '003', viewValue: 'Dropdown3', name: 'C' , value:'3' },
    { id: '004', viewValue: 'Dropdown4', name: 'D' , value:'4' },
  ];
  selectedCard = this.savedCreditCards[0];
```

This should resolve the problem.
Another way could be to wrap your html code with *ngIf like this:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedCard">
    <input placeholder="id" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.id" type="text">
    <input placeholder="viewValue" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.viewValue" type="text">
    <input placeholder="name" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.name" type="text">
    <input placeholder="value" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard.value" type="text">
</div>
```

This I think might be neater solution. In this case you don't have to assign a default value.

Comment: I try first suggestion, no error on AOT and ng serve, but inputs value are automatically update without trigger and select dropdown

Comment: Can you show that in stackblitz? Are you assigning the first element of savedCreditCards to selectedCard? If so, you can remove that.

Comment: my updated https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsuxey, I can implement this.selectedCard = [] on ngOninit to remove it or you have better solutions ?

Comment: @hafizi did you try my solution of wrapping into a div using *ngIf? Try this forked stackblitz:-                                                                                                                         https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ojfhm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @hafizi What was the problem?

Comment: because I want to show default input value, for my use case I need to show it

Comment: @hafizi Can you try the link. I updated it now.                                                                 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ojfhm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Look at your prod configuration. You are using AOT

You might want to try "ng serve --aot" for testing

You would find that you set a string type for selectedCard due to type inference. I think the stackblitz has been updated, but be careful with your references.

I definitely agree that you are using typescript, so use an interface and get the types more explicitly defined. You could have avoided this error by using explicit types, which is the main advantage of TS